# Localize .NET assembly without source code

Tags: .net, localization, assemblies

I need to localize a .NET assembly (winforms exe), but I don't have its source code. Is there any good tool that allows this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578883/a-net-disassembler-decompiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this: http://www.lingobit.com/solutions/dotnet/dotnet_localization.html

> Lingobit Localizer uses binary
>   localization to translate .NET
>   application from one language to
>   another. Lingobit extracts all
>   localizable resources such as strings,
>   menus and forms directly from assembly
>   file (*.exe, *.dll).

Answer (score 1):

For analyzing it and finding out the way of accessing resources you might want to use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). Depending on what you find out, you'll probably want to create resource files / satellite assemblies or localize it in a respective way.

Answer (score 0):

My tool of choice was [Passolo](http://www.sdl.com/en/sites/sdl-passolo/about/) (not free) but it will only help you if your winform application is localizable (i.e. strings, layout... are stored in a resx file).