# How does Application.Restart work in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

This question is not about how to restart an application. I am already achieving that by using a Mutex and a secondary starter application. I had to resort to that after facing some problems using Application.Restart.

In any case, not being fluent with IL, I was wondering if someone could explain how Application.Restart works in the first place. It is a call to the runtime but what exactly does the runtime do? How does it close the existing instance and how does it know when to launch a new one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ... not being fluent with IL, ...

Have you considered using a [decompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/578883/21567) (Reflector, dotPeek) or, even better, the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) code of the .NET framework?

Anyway.

At a casual look it does the following:

- In all below cases, the current instance is terminated using `Application.ExitInternal()`. That is the gist of the public `Application.Exit()` method, eliding some security checks/asserts.
- See if it can determine the `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`. If that is `null` the call the `Application.Restart()` was most likely done from unmanaged code and the operation throws a `NotSupportedException` to the caller.
- See if the current process is `ieexec.exe`, if so use it to restart the application (for more information about `ieexec.exe` see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822485)). Actually that is pretty much also a `Process.Start()` call to `ieexec.exe`, but the command line arguments are not gathered by `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` (see below), but by reading the `APP_LAUNCH_URL` application domain data.
- See if the application is a click-once application (`ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed`), if so call an CLR internal native code to (re)launch that: `CorLauncApplication`. The only publicly available source code that somewhat resembles the native parts of the CLR is the shared source CLI (sscli), which is based on the .NET 2.0 framework and also is partly incomplete. It contains a definition for that function (`clr\src\vm\hosting.cpp`), but it is only a stub. In the end it will use some means to restart the process (e.g. Win32's `CreateProcess` API).
- Else: the application is a "regular" .NET application. `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` is used to recreate the original command line and `Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath)` is used to restart the application.

The use of the `Application.Exit`-mechanism to try to end the current instance is probably the reason why you find it unreliable. Forms that cancel the send closing event can interrupt it. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95098/why-is-application-restart-not-reliable) SO question.

Comment: Bah, your answer is so much better than mine, I might as well just delete mine :(. +1 to you good sir!

Comment: @Christian.K: Who calls the `Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath)` ?

Comment: @joe The thread that called `Application.Restart()` it's the last thing the function does before it returns.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. I'm not sure why I did not use a decompiler. In any case, would you endorse the usage of a mutex with a secondary starter application as an acceptable method?

Comment: It all depends on how your application is deployed, if you are using ClickOnce you can just call [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.update.aspx) (then `Application.Restart()` after that, in fact that use case is on the MSDN page for `Restart`) However for most cases a separate updater stub application is the way I would do it.