# Git revert to previous version does not return all files that were commited

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-revert

So I recently had an issue were I messed up pretty bad and bricked my application so I used git to revert back to the previous version once doing so the .sln file was corrupted and now I have absoluty no way of getting my code back except the .exe file I have tried using reflector but its not giving me back the entire source code including all the forms,designers, and .sln file

If anyone can also help me understand why git completly corrupted my project files that would also be helpful

EDIT:
Here is an image of the project after reverting you will notice in the bottom console theres a bunch of "File not found" errors in the console and in the solution explorer you can see a bunch of warning images next to the files that went found...which is basically my whole project

[image: Screenshot]

For some reason git never saved my project files and I stored my project on github and made changes directly within the projects git folder so I could ave all the files in one place and git was supposed to make it easy to revert changes if something were to brick the application...

I really need something to get my work back I spent weeks building this It would be an absolute nightmare to rebuild this from scratch

EDIT 2:
As you can see in this image I added 58 files to the project and EditHeader was in fact in the commit
[image: 1.png]

Now as you can see in this picture when reverting the project its only returning 28 files and they all have errors
[image: 2.png]

Comment: How'd you revert back, exactly?

Comment: Define "completely corrupted". What does it look like? What does Visual Studio say about it? Why can't you go back to a working version?

Comment: on the git desktop client you can see your commit history right click->revert to this commit

Comment: @CodeCaster edited question

Comment: So you never committed your .cs files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A .net disassembler/decompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578883/a-net-disassembler-decompiler)

Comment: @CodeCaster thats the thing I did commit them because when I make changes to the forms I saved them immediatly on git just in case something happened so i know they were added to github

Comment: I already looked at that question btw reflector doesnt work,teerik cost about $2000 for one license(pointless just to get my work back) and the others work the same as reflector they only give back the assembly info and class info it doesnt return the designer forms,.sln files, or anything important that i need to continue my work

Comment: does `git log` list all the commits you made?

Comment: yea i have a list of all commits made

Comment: @CodeCaster see Edit2

Comment: @ImranAli see Edit2

Comment: @Makoto see Edit2

Comment: Can you run `git status` in the console and post what it returns?

Comment: In Git, "revert" does not mean "revert *to*". That is, suppose you have ten versions of a project, which we'll just number: v1, v2, ..., v9, v10. Most people would say that "revert to version 2" means "get what's in version 2". That's not what *Git* means by "revert". What Git means is: compare version 2 to version 1, to see what changed. Then, make backing-out changes to version 10 to produce a new version 11, that's mostly like version 10, minus whatever changed from v1 to v2.

Comment: If you want to get version 2 itself back, the verb to command Git to do this is `git checkout`.

Comment: ^files in git have a bunch of `<<<<<<<HEAD` Thrown everywhere in the code causing the .sln file to not load after getting all my files back